# Using LESS CSS, can I multiple a "property" by an amount? For example: width x 1.26?

Tags: css, less

Here's my CSS:

```
        div {
        border: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: width * 1.26411765;
    }
```

I'd like "width" to be the current pixel width of the element. Does that make sense? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
div {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: @div-width;
    height: (@div-width * 1.26411765);
}
```

See: http://lesscss.org/#-operations

EDIT: Having just read your question properly (oops) you can access javascript from less to get values. See the link above and scroll further down the page. I've never actually tried it though.

Comment: Thanks Gary - but I'm actually looking for the computed value of the width property, not a value I specify. Does that make sense?

Comment: Added a note regarding accessing javascript.